# Determine, if a given number is a factor of another number (30)

Tags: java

```
package cornett1;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ProgramOne {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int nmbr;
        nmbr = Integer.valueOf(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter a number less than 1000"));

        {
            if ((nmbr % 2) == 0) {
                System.out.println(nmbr + "Is even.");
            }
            System.out.println(nmbr + "Is odd.");
        }

        if ((nmbr % 5) == 0) {
            System.out.print(nmbr + "is a multiple of 5.");
        }
    }
}
```

Now I need to see, if `nmbr` is a factor of 30

Comment: by googling and researching that. this is not even programming question. it is math question

Comment: Do you mean "factor" of 30, or "multiple" of 30?  The only numbers that are _factors_ of 30 are 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 15, 30.  The numbers that are _multiples_ of 30 are 0, 30, 60, 90, 120, ...

Comment: @KickButtowski "this is not even programming question. it is math question" - That doesn't make sense to me.  This looks like a programming question to me.

Comment: the same way you did for 2 and 5

Comment: A cursory Google search will reveal a number of implementations and examples to select from.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown you can agree to disagree, yet this is math question to me

Comment: Might want to fix your actual code as well.

Comment: @KickButtowski Part of the reason that it is a valid programming question is it that he may be wondering if there is an operator that works like the `%` operator, but the other way around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`nmbr` is a factor of 30 is the same as saying 30 is a multiple of `nmbr`. So just use the `%` operator again.
You do have to guard against `nmbr` being zero, which would cause a exception.

```
if (nmbr>0 && 30%nmbr==0) {
    // nmbr is a factor of 30
}
```